# Eclipse configuration for Hadoop development

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop.I tried running example programs like wordcount and PI through linux terminal.Now want to try those with eclipse.Can anybody please share how to configure Eclipse for Hadoop development? I am using hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Vm.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reference these libraries in your Eclipse project in which you are going to use Hadoop. And that's all.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Maven Project in Eclipse and add the following dependency to the pom.xml and save the file. It will build the workspace and add all the hadoop jars to the libraries.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses!!.

i found similar jars in following dirs:
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn

I created a user library and added it to java bulid path of my eclipse project and executed the program successfully!.
Also i found this link useful: http://www.kishorer.in/2014/10/running-wordcount-mapreduce-example-in.html